# Jenkins - Different result from pipeline and freestyle build (carton install failed to install some modules)

Tags: perl, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Perl project, including `cpanfile`.

```
REPO/
  Jenkinsfile
  PROJECT1/
    cpanfile
    local/
  PROJECT2/
    cpanfile -> ../PROJECT1/cpanfile
    local/   -> ../PROJECT1/local
  ...
```

I'm running Jenkins in a Docker container from `jenkinsci/blueocean` image.

Now I want to build, test, and deploy this Perl project using Jenkins.

At first, I tried to use a freestyle build. This is my build script:

```
docker run -t --rm \
  -v $WORKSPACE:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp/PROJECT1 \
  localhost:20000/perl-carton:5.26 \
  carton install
```

- `localhost:20000/perl-carton:5.26` is a Docker image that I'd built from `perl:5.26`. I added to this image some Perl modules like Carton and some dependencies like libgd-dev for my project.
- I mounted the workspace to `/usr/src/myapp` and set a working directory of the container to `PROJECT1` below the workspace, because `cpanfile` is there.

This `docker run ...` command works well in my host machine(replacing `$WORKSPACE` with `$PWD`).

This command works well also in the Jenkins container.

Then, I tried to use Jenkins Pipeline. I made `Jenkinsfile` like this:

```
// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'localhost:20000/perl-carton:5.26'
//                    args '-v $WORKSPACE:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp/PROJECT1'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'cd PROJECT1 && carton install'
            }
    ...
}
```

- I commented out `-v ... -w ...` because I'd found, from an output, that Jenkins mounts its workspace and set the working directory to that workspace by force: `docker run ... -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JOBNAME --volumes-from DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID ...`. So my `-w ...` option was overwritten.

I hoped this pipeline would do the same job. But when I run this pipeline, it fails to install some modules.

```
[AppStore(pipeline)] Running shell script
+ cd PROJECT1
+ carton install
Installing modules using /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JOBNAME/PROJECT1/cpanfile
! Installing DBD::SQLite failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1519351987.18/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'DBD::SQLite' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for DBIx-Class-0.082840.
...
Installing modules failed
```

Finally, I tried to modify Jenkinsfile not to use `agent docker` and let it run docker in a shell command:

```
agent any
steps {
    sh 'docker run -t --rm -v $WORKSPACE:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp/PROJECT1 localhost:20000/perl-carton:5.26 carton install'
}
```

It was successful as I'd expected.

I have no idea of what causes this difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.

I'd named the pipeline job `TestProject(pipeline)` in Jenkins.

Job name contains parentheses,
so does the name of workspace directory,
and BOOM inside a shell command...

```
cc -c  -I/Users/gypark/temp/b(test)/local/..omitted../Install
  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -O3   
  -DVERSION=\"0.005\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.005\"  
  "-I/Users/gypark/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18/lib/5.18.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   filehandles.c
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(
```

I made a new pipeline project, without a parenthesis in its name. And everything worked succesfully.